# How to click on elements inside an iframe with robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, robotframework

Select Frame  index=1

click element =  XXXXXXXX

but this step is not working

error : Not found frames[1]

Comment: `selectFrame = index=1` doesn't look like proper robot syntax. Please include the _exact_ code you are using.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley  Select Frame  | index = 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select Frame takes a *locator* as an argument.

```
Select Frame | {your iframe xpath/locator}
```